# Replace character(s) in list a with character from list b

Tags: python, list

I have two text files:

clues.txt – contains letter/symbol pairs:

```
A#
M*
N%
```

words.txt – contains list of scrambled words:

```
#+/084&"
#3*#%#+
8%203:
,1$&
!-*%
.#7&33&
#*#71%
&-&641'2
#))85
9&330*
```

I've read the contents of each file into a list, using list comprehensions:

```
clues = [line.strip() for line in open("clues.txt", 'r')]

words = [line.strip() for line in open("words.txt", 'r')]
```

How would I dynamically replace all instances of each symbol in the `words` list, with the corresponding symbol from the `clues` list?

So, each instance of `#` in `words` is replaced with an `A`, each instance of `*` in `words` is replaced with an `M`, and so forth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `str.replace` creating pairs of substrings out of each line in clues then iterate over reassigning line to the updated value of the line after replacing:

```
with  open("clues.txt", 'r') as f, open("words.txt", 'r') as f2:
    clues = [list(line.rstrip()) for line in f]
    for line in f2:
        for rep, orig in clues:
            line = line.replace(orig, rep)
        print(line.rstrip())
```

Output:

```
A+/084&"
A3MANA+
8N203:
,1$&
!-MN
.A7&33&
AMA71N
&-&641'2
A))85
9&330M
```

Or use [str.translate](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_translate.htm):

```
with  open("clues.txt", 'r') as f, open("words.txt", 'r') as f2:
    # keys are ord of character to replace, 
    # values are character to replace with
    d = {ord(k): v for v, k in (list(line.rstrip()) for line in f)}
    for line in f2:
        print(line.translate(d).rstrip())
```

Output:

```
A+/084&"
A3MANA+
8N203:
,1$&
!-MN
.A7&33&
AMA71N
&-&641'2
A))85
9&330M
```

For python2 you need to use `string.maketrans` to create the table:

```
from string import maketrans
with open("clues.txt", 'r') as f, open("words.txt", 'r') as f2:
    # separate A -> # ...
    a, b = zip(*(list(line.rstrip()) for line in f))
    # create table where # maps to A, * -> M and % -> N
    tbl = maketrans("".join(b), "".join(a))
    for line in f2:
        # translate each string using our mapping table
        print(line.translate(tbl).rstrip())
```

Output:

```
A+/084&"
A3MANA+
8N203:
,1$&
!-MN
.A7&33&
AMA71N
&-&641'2
A))85
9&330M
```

Python3 requires a mapping of the `ord` of the character to replace to the string you want to replace it with, in python 2 we do something similar but have to use [string.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) to create our table which ends up being the strings `'#*%', 'AMN'`.

Answer (score 1):

The most effective way to do that is to use [`string.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate):

```python
import string

with open('clues.txt', 'r') as cluesf, open('words.txt', 'r') as wordsf:
    clues = [line.strip() for line in cluesf]
    trans = string.maketrans(''.join([c[1:] for c in clues]), ''.join([c[0] for c in clues]))
    words = [line.strip().translate(trans) for line in wordsf]

    print(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, and there might be various constraints. Like the size of the words file, whether clues are always 2 characters with 1st character being the to-replace-with and 2nd character being the to-be-replaced. Here is a simple solution, which you can build on.

Instead of reading the words into a list, first read it as a string (assuming a file of reasonable size), and then replace it with your clues, and after that split it. So that you can have the replacements only once per clue. Like:

```
with open('words.txt') as wfd: file_as_string = wfd.read()
for clue in clues: words_str = file_as_string.replace(clue[1], clue[0])
words = [word.strip() for word in file_as_string.split('\n')]
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert your `clues` to a mapping of actual key/value pairs:

```
clues = [line.strip() for line in open("clues.txt", 'r')]
clues = dict([(k, v) for v, k in clues])
```

Then iterate through each character of each word in `words`:

```
for word in words:
    for i, c in enumerate(word):
        if c in clues:
            word[i] = clues[c]
```

*Unfortunately* this isn't the most efficient and has at worst an `O^2` complexity.

**Update:** An improved version of this:

```
clues = dict([(k, v) for v, k in map(str.strip, open("clues.txt", "r"))])
with open("words.txt", "r") as f:
    for i, c in enumerate(word):
        if c in clues:
            word[i] = clues[c]
```